# Liquibase doesn't honour RAISERROR of SQL server

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

We have a number of configuration scripts which are a bit complicated. Those scripts are using a number of available stored procedure in our database to insert the configuration data. If any script attempts to insert invalid data, stored procedures will make a call to

```
RAISERROR @msg, 16, 1
```

And then the SP will return. The SPs start their own named transactions and they will rollback/commit the named transaction, however, LB doesn't detect the error raised and it takes the execution as a successful execution. But we don't want to continue if that happens.

failOnError in the changeSets are set to true but LB still proceeds. Even in DATABASECHANGELOG that failed changeset marked as executed as if it was successful.

We also tried removing nested transactions (named transactions), no luck.

We removed the name from the transaction and just using BEGIN TRAN, the LB execution stops at the incorrect script but the problem is, LB fails to commit its own transaction and can't release the lock so it remains LOCKED.

Is there anyway to tell LB that an error happened and make it stop?

> We are using Liquibase 3.5.0. and Microsoft SQL Server

=== EDIT

So after debugging Liquibase, we found two things:

1. When connected to MS SQL Server, if a RAISERROR occurs and there are also resultsets in the script, it won't throw exception unless we make a call to statement.getMoreResults(). The same thing happens with Sybase (we tested it with Sybase too). So we thought maybe in LB, after executing the statement we need to make a call to getMoreResults() until it throws exception or it returns false which means no error happened.
2. A script makes a call to a stored procedure. The stored procedure, has 'BEGIN TRAN' and at the end it either COMMIT or ROLLBACK. If a rollback occurs, it also does RAISERROR. Note that our scripts don't do any update/insert, they are only providing the data in a temp table, so we don't do transaction handling in our scripts. In this scenario, consider we added code to make a call to getMoreResults(), the exception is throws correctly but then in LB, the executor tries to database.rollback() and then later again in StandardLockService, before releasing the lock, it tries to database.rollback() which ends in exception because our SP has rolled back the transaction already. This last rollback in LB, causes the error raised by JDBC to be swallowed and as the result not only do we see the error that caused it but also the lock remained unreleased and this is the most concern because even if we re-run the script and fix it, the lock hasn't been released and we need to do it manually.

One may argue that our transaction handling is not correct but all I am trying to say is that releasing lock should not be affecting if our script is incorrect. LB should be releasing the lock and throw exception or continue if a script/changeset is not run successfully.

Comment: I have noted this as well on very simple scripts which do only a few inserts. The solution for me was to separate each insert with a batch separator(GO). I am using Liquibase formatted sql.

Comment: To my knowledge Liquibase uses a JDBC connection to the db. Do you have a DB tool at hand that also uses the JDBC driver? You could manually run the SQL statements that liquibase would execute and see what happens. Maybe the error is not handed back to the sql statement that called the SP? And thus not reported back via JDBC to the calling code? I have no knowledge of SQL-Server dbs. It's just a hint on how you could maybe narrow the cause of this...

Comment: @PeterHenell Our script aren't LB formatted. A lot of them are being moved from a legacy system. They do multiple things, for example, inserting records, a dozen of checks for dependencies making sure no invalid data is inserted, etc.

Comment: @Jens I haven't run them with a JDBC tool but if you run the same script in Salford server studio, it prints out the log in red as error occurred. I will try with JDBC when I am back at work

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can try the `THROW` command, which is batch-aborting, while `RAISERROR` is not. Else you might need to trap and check the messages coming back from SQL Server. These are typically just PRINT statements, but depending on the driver/connection settings, errors can be treated as messages. In that case, you need to trap messages and check their "state" / "severity" / "level" to see if they are an error or informational.

Comment: @srutzky Unfortunately we can't use THROW. This is because our scripts have to be Sybase compatible this is as per our company's policy

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is facing this too: In my case I had a very complex SQL script only for MS SQL Server. This also failed to stop the execution of the LB changes if an error occures in the SQL script, anyway if I use RAISERROR or THROW.
Things I need to do, to get it to work:

- remove (or comment) all places where resultsets were created (SELECT)
- start the SQL script with "SET NOCOUNT ON;" to avoid results from
  insert or update (... lines affected)
- end the SQL script with "SET NOCOUNT OFF;" to enable LB to work properly just after executing the SQL script (set EXECTYPE)

Answer (score 0):

Use the precondition https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html

create another changeset and check for the execution result before proceeding to next.